# Removing Symbols and Spaces from a Phone Number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a phone number variable that is assigned a value.

```
let phone: String = "+1 (512) 477-2900"
```

I want to remove all the spaces and characters including "(", "+", ")" and "-" from the phone number. How can I do that?

```
// remove the spaces
let formattedPhone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

I don't know how to remove other characters as mentioned earlier.

Comment: The same way as what you already did.

Comment: I also want to remove ( and ) and -.

Comment: Then do so. Replace occurrences of each of those with nothingness, as you already did.

Comment: You can use more elegant approaches like custom character set, but I don't understand the issue. If you know how to remove a space you know how to remove anything

Comment: thanks! I was just looking for a much better way. I will use replaceOccurences.

Comment: That's not what you said in your question. You said "I don't know how to remove other characters as mentioned earlier." I'm telling you that you _do_ know. There are lots of "better" ways. But the way you're doing it is a way that you know and it works fine.

Comment: If you want to manipulate or otherwise phone numbers, I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to remove all the characters in the string other than numbers.

```
let updatedPhone = phone.filter{$0.isNumber}
print(updatedPhone) // 15124772900
```

Comment: The filtering can also be written as `phone.filter(\.isNumber)`

Comment: You might want to use `.isWholeNumber`. See the documentation for both `.isNumber` and `.isWholeNumber` for examples of how they work.